# IF with multiple conditions not working

Tags: php

I am trying to create an if statement with multiple conditions but it won't work and perhaps it is my syntax.

I have two post variables, which both give me the value fine elsewhere on my page. They are:

$_POST['text']
$_POST['rating'] //can be G, PG or R

What I am trying to do is make my word filter code work only if the rating equals "G"
What is currently happening though is that the filter is flagging a bad word regardless of the rating and ignoring my IF rating = G part.

```
if (isset($_POST['text']) and $_POST['rating'] =  "G") {

//give warning if bad words are used

}
```

Comment: if (isset($_POST['text']) and $_POST['rating'] ==  "G") {

//give warning if bad words are used

}

Comment: Wht's the meaning of "and" here? try && man?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['rating'] =="G") {

//give warning if bad words are used

}?>
```

use it like this

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the symbol version of the syntax.

- `&&` for and
- `||` for or

Also, `=` does not mean equals in an if statement.  That is the syntax for setting a variable.
You would say `==` (equals to).

To say "not equals" you would use `!=` or `!=`

```
if (isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['rating'] ==  "G") {

//give warning if bad words are used

}
```